# Upgraded IntelliJ and Spock disappeared from Testing Library List

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I recently upgraded to IntelliJ 2023.3 and now when I hit Ctrl Alt T to create a test, the Testing Library list includes junits and Test NG, but no spock. I can still run my existing Spock tests, but it won't let me create a new one.

Went back through IntelliJ setup for spock, but didn't see anything I should be trying.

Stumped as to what to try next.

Please help! I can no longer write code without my unit tests. :)

Comment: Have you been using any Spock plugin which might not be compatible with the newest Intellij anymore?

Answer (score 6):

This is an IntelliJ bug.

Here is the issue reporting it is missing: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316239

And this is the ticket the fix of which supposedly broke it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-315375

Just create test file manually. Navigating to existing test classes still works.